Как сделать нумерованный список в adobe after effects?
Мне надо сделать анимацию с нумерованным списком. Чтобы квадраты с текстом "Задача 1, задача 2 ..." двигались в лево и первый с лева пропадал, а после следующее движение. Можно ли это как-то осуществить или только в ручную копировать и дублировать?
(P. S. Я знаю что есть повторитель и я прикрепил скрин с ним. Но он не вешается на текст, можно ли как-то сделать структуру из шейпа-квадрата и текста чтобы после сверху накинуть повторитель, притом как-то выражением в тексте менять цифру в зависимости от того какая это по счёту копия?)

